# Crystal Report converting value to number with symbol

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, numbers, logic, symbols

I have an issue with a Crystal Report that I'm creating.  I am using fields from a database and am pulling in the result value where the analysis field is equal to certain values. 
In the condition the first check looks at the analysis field and checks if its equal to "Conf".  The result for this is "<10"
The second check looks at the analysis field and checks if its equal to "Original".  The result for this is "20".

I want the results to display in the order above however with the following basic logic it returns the result of 20.

```
if analysis = "conf" then result
else if analysis = "Original" then result
```

I was having this issue with multiple records however solved it by converting both results to numbers (toNumber(Result)).  However this record has the less than symbol contained within the field value which causes the conf result to "be skipped" and will display the original result instead.  I've tried a few things without success.  Here is the code for the condition of where I'm at below.  I fell this is way to complex logic but I've just added to it as I've had ideas and it shows what I've tried.

```
if {UNITS} = "CFU_G" then
if {ANALYSIS} = "CONF" and
{RESULT}="" or
{RESULT} = "0" then 0
else if {ANALYSIS} = "CONF"
then if isNumeric({RESULT}) then
tonumber({RESULT}) else
tonumber(Replace ({RESULT}, "<", ""))

else 

if {UNITS} = "CFU_G" then
if {ANALYSIS} = "Original" and
{RESULT}="" or
{RESULT} = "0" then 0
else if {ANALYSIS} = "Original"
then if isNumeric({RESULT}) then
tonumber({RESULT}) else
tonumber(Replace ({RESULT}, "<", ""))
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Your explanation us bit confusing... can you add what is expected and what you sre getting?

Comment: Could it be a problem with case (CONF vs Conf vs conf)? Are you sure about the precedence of logic operators (maybe you should use parenthesis in the OR operations)?

Comment: Ok, apologise for not being clearer.  I found a solution creating a variable doing a loop.  See answer for Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution I came up with.

```
Field 1
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar vResult := "";

Field 2
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar vResult;
vResult :=  if {RESULT.UNITS} = "CFU_G"
and {RESULT.ANALYSIS} = "CRA_LIS_ENU_CONF_MPCRAM29" 
then {RESULT.FORMATTED_ENTRY}

else if {RESULT.ANALYSIS} = "CRA_LIST_ENU_MPCRAM29"
and {RESULT.UNITS} = "CFU_G"
and vResult = ""
then {RESULT.FORMATTED_ENTRY}

Field 3
whileprintingrecords;
stringvar vResult;
vResult;
```